# How could we calculate numerically $\hat{v} = \alpha_{0}(I−P)^{-1}$, as the limit of the recurrence $v(t+1) = v(t)P + \alpha_{0}$?

Tags: stochastic-processes, probability-distributions, markov-chains

I'm working with my colleague to introduce a potential therapeutic model. We use the framework of adaptive dynamics. But we are stuck at some steps of the continuous-time Markov chain.

In the appendix of this article ([1](https://doi.org/10.1007/s11538-011-9638-4)), the author stated:

> $$c_{N,N'} = c^{0,+}_{N,N'} + c^{0,-}_{N,N'} + c^{+,0}_{N,N'} + c^{-,0}_{N,N'} + \mu.\tag{16}$$
>
> With the above-mentioned rates we obtain the forward Kolmogorov equations of
> the Markov chain. Let $A$ denote the corresponding matrix where all these rates are
> collected, and note that the diagonal elements $−c_{N, N'}$
> are negative. If we write the matrix $A$ as $A = L + U + D$, where $D$ is a diagonal
> matrix, and $L$ and $U$ are lower and upper triangular matrices, we can
> write the transition probability matrix $P$ of the embedded
> discrete-time chain as $P = −D^{−1}(L+U)$. The probability distribution of
> the Markov chain after $t$ transitions is $\alpha_{t} = \alpha_{0}P^{t}$, and the average
> number of times that the Markov chain visits state $i$ is
> $$\hat{v} = \sum_{t=0}^{\infty} \alpha_{t} = \sum_{t=0}^{\infty}\alpha_{0} P^{t}.\tag{17}\label{17}$$
>
> From \eqref{17} we observe that $\alpha_{0} = \hat{v} − \hat{v}P = \hat{v}(I − P)$, and thus we obtain
> (Kemeny and Snell 1960) $\hat{v} = \alpha_{0}(I − P)^{-1}$, which can be calculated
> numerically (Faddeev and Faddeeva 1963) as the limit of the recurrence
> $v(t + 1) = v(t)P + \alpha_{0}$.

and in the appendix of another reference ([2](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.tpb.2008.01.002)) for the same author he stated:

> The initial state is  $\alpha_{n,1} = \hat{p}_{n}$ for $0\le n\le K-1$
> and otherwise  $\alpha_{n,n'} = 0$. The recurrence becomes
> $$v_{n,n'}(t + 1) = \frac{c^{0,−}_{n,n'+1}}{c_{n,n'+1}} v_{n,n'+1}(t) + \frac{c^{+,0}_{n−1,n'}}{c_{n−1,n'}} v_{n−1,n'}(t) + \frac{c^{−,0}_{n+1,n'}}{c_{n+1,n'}} v_{n+1,n'}(t) + \frac{c^{0,+}_{n,n'−1}}{c_{n,n'−1}} v_{n,n'−1}(t) +  \alpha_{n,n'}\tag{A.5}$$
> for $n\ge 0$, $n'\ge 1$, $n+n'\le K$. The boundary conditions are
> $v_{n,0}=0$, $v_{-1,n'}=0$  and $v_{i,K+1-i}=0$,  because then the
> population size $ n + n' = i + K + 1 − i = K + 1 $ is above the
> maximum allowed.

My question is, if we already have the  transition probability matrix $P$, how could we calculate numerically  $\hat{v} = \alpha_{0}(I − P)^{-1}$,  as the limit of the recurrence $v(t + 1) = v(t)P + \alpha_{0}$?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks